# How do I use jQuery get the ID of the div which has been clicked on?

Tags: jquery

I need to get the ID of the clicked-on div.

Now when I click on status class I an returned undefined id.

Here is my javascript code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(".status").bind('click', $.proxy(function() {
        var status = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(status);
    }, this));
});​
```

and HTML

```
<div class="status" id="s_1">111111</div>
<div class="status" id="s_3">33333</div>
<div class="status" id="s_2">222222</div>
```

How should I get the correct id value?

Comment: ii will gives you id of all elemets matched to this selector. use "each"

Answer (score 27):

I'm not sure why you're using $.proxy. Removing it should get you the desired results.

```
$('.status').click(function(event) {
    var status = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

If you still want to use proxy you can access the clicked element through `event.currentTarget`

```
$(".status").bind('click', $.proxy(function(event) {
    var status = $(event.currentTarget).attr('id');
    alert(status);
}, this));
```

Comment: As my comment above: Why do use jQuery to get the element id? and you're missing the dot before the status selector.

Comment: because that is what he's doing.

Answer (score 5):

How about:

```
$('div').on('click', function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Does this have to work only for divs with class `status`?  If so, try:

```
$('div.status').on('click', function(){
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: um I did not downvote but `div.status' would work as a selector.

Comment: Now it has other mistake, this is now searching for nodes inside a div with the status class. Are you fimilar with jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

use event.target to reference that element

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $(".status").bind('click', $.proxy(function(event) {
            var status = $(event.target).attr('id');
          alert(status);
    }, this));
});
```

see in action: http://jsfiddle.net/vNaqR/

Comment: NOTE: you could use `var status = event.target.id;` but I followed your code on that part.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".divField").click(function() {
    alert("id : " + $(this).attr("id"));
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <h1>For finding id click below text</h1>
  <div id="id1" value="Example 1" class="divField">My id is <b>id1</b></div>
  <div id="id2" value="Example 2" class="divField">My id is <b>id2</b></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('selector').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        alert($(this).attr('id'))
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Explanation of PROXY issue :

Be carefull by using $.proxy().
It calls a function (here the parameter 1) using the specified context (here the parameter 2) instead of using the context in which the event is triggered.

In the main question, the specified context is $(document) so.
In this way, the function try to get the ID of the document instead of the ID of the object on which the event is triggered (the $('.status') element).

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to display the hidden div when I click on the button,then every time user click on button display more indexes.

That's not working since on the list is always empty if I'm on the add mode not edit(display the div when it's edit)

```
                       <li>
                        <button type="button" name="addAnotherButton" class="btnFwd gradient smButtonStyling" 
                        onClick="showInput();">
                            <img src="/Common/web/static/images/add.png" class="smbtnIcon" />
                            Add Another 
                    </button>
                </li>

                <li>
                           <c:forEach items="${planInfoList}" var="planInfo" varStatus="status">
                        <div id="uploadBody[${status.index}]" style='display = none'>
                            <label class="adminFormLabel">Title:</label>
                            <form:input path="planInfoList[${status.index}].title" onfocus="this.select();" maxlength="50" size="30"/>
                            <label class="adminFormLabel">Plan Number:</label>
                            <form:input path="planInfoList[${status.index}].planNumber" size="10" maxlength="10"/>
                        </div>
                    </c:forEach>
                </li>
```

JS:

```
var found = 0;
    if ($('#uploadBody' + i).hide()) {
        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if (found == 0) {
                $('#uploadBody' + i).show();
            }
            found++;
        }       
        }
```